# Dynamic default values for input box in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, service, watch

I have a value which i get from a controller and two input box.
I need that whenever i enter any value in one input box. difference of the value retrieved from controller and  input box get displayed in the other input box using angularJs.
e.g:-
{{sum}} --> is the value which I get from controller.

```
<input  type="number" ng-model="firstnumber" />
<input type="number" ng-model="secondnumber"/>
```

What I tried was making service for setting and getting the sum value and watch to change the value every time a value is changed.

My service is :-

```
angular.module('myapp').service("cmModalService", function($scope){
var sum= ={};
    getSum = function(){
        return sum;
    }

    setSum = function(value){
        sum=value;
    };
});
```

In a controller I have defined

```
$scope.$watch('firstnumber', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
var sum=cmModalService.getSum();    
if(newValue!=null)
{ secondnumber = sum -firstnumber;
}
});

$scope.$watch('secondnumber', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
var sum=cmModalService.getSum();    
if(newValue!=null)
{ firstnumber = sum -secondnumber;
}
});
```

But whenever i change values in input box the flow never goes to watch method, and the values doesn't change.
Is there any other method also to achieve this.?

I have tried using ng-change also but still not able to get the exact result.

And inside controller i have defined the change methods as

```
$scope.changefirstnumber=function(firstnumber, sum){
   $scope.secondnumber = sum- firstnumber;
   };


   $scope.changesecondnumber=function(secondnumber, sum){
   $scope.firstnumber= sum- secondnumber;
   };
```

and in html

[Plunker link]

Comment: why cant you just do `{{firstnumber + secondnumber}}` ?

Comment: I don't get it, do you mean you would like to fill another inputbox with the sum of the values from the other 2?

Comment: I mean when I enter a value in input box the value in other input box shoul d automatically come as {{sum-firstnumber}} and vice-versa

Comment: what is `sum` equal to? According to your service, it is an empty object. How do you plan to add a number to an object? You can't the way you are describing above

Comment: the sum i am getting from another controller

Comment: That is relevant to your question and you should include it. Is `firstnumber` and `secondnumber` the same controller? I still dont get why sum is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the scoped variable. Try this.

```
$scope.$watch('firstnumber', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
var sum=cmModalService.getSum();    
if(newValue!=null)
{ $scope.secondnumber = sum -$scope.firstnumber;
}
});

$scope.$watch('secondnumber', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
var sum=cmModalService.getSum();    
if(newValue!=null)
{ $scope.firstnumber = sum - $scope.secondnumber;
}
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QhCjjk4UstLEcGUs5Ro9?p=preview)

Comment: @pankajparkar - Thanks for adding the plunkr. I didn't get a chance to try it out.

Comment: It is working because of the intended logic in it. Otherwise $watch will keep executing indefinitely because one watch is modifying other watch's values.

Comment: thats what I trying to point out..but this got fails in this scenario..:p

Comment: @ronnie I have edit the question so you will may understand what i really want

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
With some new information you provided, is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/37gv1kbe/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope,cmModalService)
{
    $scope.firstnumber = 5;
    $scope.secondnumber = 10;

    $scope.$watch('firstnumber', function()
    {
        $scope.total = cmModalService.getSum() - $scope.firstnumber
    });

    $scope.$watch('secondnumber', function()
    {
        $scope.total = cmModalService.getSum() - $scope.secondnumber;
    });
});

app.controller('MySecondController', function($scope,cmModalService)
{
    $scope.rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);  
    cmModalService.setSum($scope.rand);
});

app.service('cmModalService', function()
{
    var sum;
    return {
        getSum: function()
        {
            return sum;
        },    
        setSum: function(value)
        {
            sum = value;
        }    
    }   
});
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

regarding my comment, if you need to access the total in your controller, you can just save the val of `firstnumber` and `secondnumber` like so

http://jsfiddle.net/pvqm4tcw/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.firstnumber = 5;
    $scope.secondnumber = 10;

    $scope.$watch('firstnumber', function()
    {
        $scope.total = $scope.firstnumber + $scope.secondnumber;
    });

    $scope.$watch('secondnumber', function()
    {
        $scope.total = $scope.firstnumber + $scope.secondnumber;
    });
});
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input  type="number" ng-model="firstnumber" />
        <br>
        <input type="number" ng-model="secondnumber"/>
        <br>
        {{total}}
    </div>
</body>
```

If you're using Angular 1.3+ they have a `$watchGroup` which can make the code even smaller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.firstnumber = 5;
    $scope.secondnumber = 10;

    $scope.$watchGroup(['firstnumber','secondnumber'], function()
    {
        $scope.total = $scope.firstnumber + $scope.secondnumber;
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not what i want

Comment: @Eftakhar you need to be more clear in your question then, be more specific